# Adding attribute in script from Input Javascript

Tags: javascript, paypal

In one of my webpage i need to add PayPal payment button, in which value has to be entered by input.

i  got this script to add PayPal button:

```
 <script 
async="async" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=email@adress.com" 
        data-button="paynow"
        data-amount="5"
        data-currency="USD">
</script>
```

Now i have to change the value of "data-amount" every time by Input from User.
I tried to use onkeyup, setAttribute but both don't seem to work. Please suggest what should i do or where i'm making mistake.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script>
    function showMe(e) {
    var x=e.value;
    document.getElementsById("paypal").setAttribute("data-amount", "x");
    }
    </script>

    <body>
    Amount: <input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" onkeyup="showMe(this)" required>

  <script id="paypal"
    async="async" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/js/external/paypal-button.min.js?merchant=payPalmerchantId" 
        data-button="paynow" 
        data-currency="USD">
</script>
<br><br><br>
<p>You will be redirected to Payment Gateway..</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: also set the src attribute once again, so the script is loaded once again

Comment: @DineshKumarDJ How to set the Src again...? i don't have much idea about JS  Please suggest :(

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
     function showMe(e) {
          var x=e.value;

            $("#paypal").attr("data-amount", x);

         }
```

or doing everything in jquery

```
      $("#amount").on('input', function() {
 $("#paypal").attr("data-amount", $("#amount").val());
    });
```

Comment: i tried adding the jquery 1.11.2 and the 2nd code... but still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with PayPal scripts, but as I know, such types of embedding set attributes and any other features at step of initializing...

So you have to reload your script.

You could also search for the ability to change attributes with the help of API provided by PayPal

Update:

I've just tried to insert your code into my local page...
Your script searches for element with id "paypal", but if you look at your code after tha page loads, you won't see even "script" tag which refers to the paypal js file. You'll see a form instead.  Try to search for "script" word here and you won't find that  tag. At least this reason is why your script doesn't work.

Comment: @TobiMcNAmobi How you did ? Please suggest me changes. I'm not much familiar with JavaScript.